# UIViewController designated initializer vs loadView method

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have my view controller class MyVC extending from UIViewController class. In the designated initializer I change the background color to GREEN as following

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I also have the loadView method that creates a new UIView object and changes its color to RED

```
- (void)loadView
{
    UIView* view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self setView:view];
    [view release];
}
```

The designated initializer is called before loadView call. So I expect that my view color (which I set GREEN in designated initializer) should become RED (which I did in loadView). 
I see my color GREEN and if I comment that GREEN color line in designated initializer, then I see the RED color. So why is it not overriding the view properties in loadView method if it is called after initializer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `-loadView` is to, uh, load the view. It's called when you access the view controller's `view` property and the value of that property is nil. In this case, you're accessing `self.view` in your initializer, so that's when `-loadView` gets called. You set the view's background after that happens, so the view ends up with a green background.

Comment: I did not understand how in my initializer am I assigning view to self.view? Is calling [self.view setBack...] API does that implicitly?

Comment: Btw, I verified that in this case laodView is getting called. Also no where in my initializer I am setting view to self.view.

Comment: Sorry -- should have explained. UIViewController is set up to create its view lazily. It doesn't create the view until it's needed. Whenever you access `self.view` and the `view` is nil, the view controller will load the view. @robmayoff is right -- it does call `-loadView` in order to do that, but it does wherever you access `self.view`, which in this case is right in the middle of your initializer. Right after that, you set the `self.view`'s background color, and that's why your view has a green background.

Answer (score 9):

Caleb has it almost right.  When you access a view controller's `view` property, the `view` accessor method checks whether the view has been loaded yet.  If not, it calls `loadView`, then `viewDidLoad`, then returns the view.

This line in your initializer accesses the `view` property:

```
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

So to return the view, the `view` accessor calls your `loadView` method.  Your `loadView` method sets the view's background color to red.  Then your initializer sets the background color to green.

If you sprinkle some `NSLog`s in your initializer and your `loadView` method, or if you put a breakpoint in your `loadView` method, you will see that `loadView` is called from `view`, which is called from `initWithNibName:bundle:`.